# Why does git think master is ahead of the remote, when it's actually behind?

Tags: git, github

I have a repo on GitHub where someone else has created a couple of new branches, and I have clicked "merge" on the branches on GitHub to merge them into master.

On GitHub's commit history, I can see four commits: the person's commit on the branch (`hash1` and `hash2`), followed by my merge commits (`hash3` and `hash4`). This is fine.

But I am confused about my local git status, and how to get it into sync with the remote. I am on the master branch.

If I type `git whatchanged`, the last commits I see locally are the person's commit on the branch (`hash1` and `hash2`), not the remote merge commits (`hash3` and `hash4`).

If I type `git status`, I see the following:

```
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Why does git think that `hash1` and `hash2` puts it ahead of remote master? Isn't it instead *behind* master, because it doesn't have `hash3` and `hash4`?

If I type `git pull origin master`, I see:

```
From github.com:myorg/myrepo
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

So it doesn't seem to know about `hash3` and `hash4`.

I'm now scared of making a new commit locally in case I mess up master, have unnecessary extra merges, etc. What should I do to just get everything up to date with remote master, and start with a clean slate?

UPDATE: Here's the output of `git remote -v`:

```
origin  git@github.com:myorg/myrepo.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:myorg/myrepo.git (push)
```

And here's the output of `git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --all`:

```
*   2315aed (HEAD -> master) Merge branch 'master' of github.com:myorg/myrepo
|\
| *   9de7505 (origin/master) Merge pull request #12 from myorg/reposition-video
| |\
* | \   0d1d845 Merge branch 'reposition-video' of github.com:myorg/myrepo
|\ \ \
| |/ /
|/| /
| |/
| * 1067905 (origin/reposition-video, reposition-video) Move the video below the fold.
* |   a5e8d96 Merge pull request #11 from myorg/update-install-docs
|\ \
| |/
|/|
| * 9744ffa Minor documentation fixes.
|/
* 4b4d507 Update README.
* 89da81b Add latest code for feature.
```

Ah, so if I do `git log` locally I can actually see *four* merge commits, not two! They just don't show up in `git whatchanged`, which is partly why I was confused.

Question now: how can I undo these extra local merges, and get back into sync with remote, which has just two merge commits? And how did they happen in the first place - I guess there must be some automatic merging going on on during `git pull`?

Comment: Can you run `git remote -v` and `git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --all` and append the output to your question? I have the latter command bound to an alias, because it is immensely helpful to get an overview in situations like these.

Comment: If you have a merge based workflow (what GitHub gravitates towards for some reason), then you will end up with two merge commits every time you sync up.  However, you can _avoid_ one of these merge commits by _rebasing_ your local `master` on the remote when you pull.  Try this by doing `git pull --rebase origin master`.  Inspect the history and you will see that there are no new merge commits (except possibly one coming from GitHub).

Comment: Your Git appears to predate version 1.8.2, based on the output from `git pull`.  In this case you must run `git fetch` separately, to get your remote-tracking branch information updated.  (Or update Git... use `git --version` to get version information; currently Git is at 2.8.x.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force your `master` to be at `origin/master` using

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard origin/master
```

this should discard `0d1d845` and `2315aed` and your network should then look like

```
* 9de7505 (origin/master, HEAD -> master) Merge pull request #12 from myorg/reposition-video
|\ 
| * 1067905 (origin/reposition-video, reposition-video) Move the video below the fold.
* |   a5e8d96 Merge pull request #11 from myorg/update-install-docs
|\ \
| |/
|/|
| * 9744ffa Minor documentation fixes.
|/
* 4b4d507 Update README.
* 89da81b Add latest code for feature.
```

You will not break anything. In case this does not what you want or breaks unexpectedly you can go back to the "messy state" using

```
git reset --hard 2315aed
```

Comment: Phew - that solved the immediate problem, thank you! Any idea how the extra merges might have happened? I'm wondering if it's a setting I've made in git at some point.

Comment: `git pull` downloads the changes **and merges them** into your currently checked out branch. using that superlong `git log` line (create an alias for it!) and `git fetch` you can download and see what is happening on your server (`origin/master` and `origin/reposition-video` will grow and move around) without merging it into your local branches yet.

Answer (score 1):

You need to realize that anything Git reports about the status of your local `master` branch is with respect to the *local* tracking branch which tracks the real remote `master` which is on GitHub.  When you see the following:

```
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
```

it means that your local `master` is ahead of the *local* tracking branch by one commit.  It does not necessarily imply anything abiut what is actually happening on the remote.  The events leading to this state were likely the following:

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
# work work work
git commit
git status
```

Now here's where it gets juicy.  When you again did

```
git pull origin master
```

you merged all the new work on the remote `master` branch.  So now your local Git says you are up to date with the remote, and you are.  But the catch is that now the remote is behind you.  So you should also merge your local branch into the remote `master`.  Since you are using GitHub, issuing a pull request is a clean and safe way to do this.

Comment: Thanks so much! I haven't done any work locally though, that's what's confusing.

Comment: Just updated the question - it looks like there's some automatic extra merging going on during `git pull` which may be the problem... I'd like to fix this so that each new pull request doesn't result in two merge commits!

Comment: You could try `git pull --rebase origin master`  ... this will avoid the merge commit locally when pulling.